# How do I open a terminal window and execute a command after the shell has opened?

Tags: bash, command-history, gnome-terminal, bashrc

I would like to have a command or script that **opens a new gnome-terminal window with bash and loads a history file and stays open**.

I searched for how to open a terminal and execute a command without it closing, and the answers I found are essentially summarized in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3531426/4729188).

Based on these methods, I tried running the following command:

```
gnome-terminal -e "bash -c 'history -r ~/history.txt; exec $SHELL'"
```

However, the history that appears in the new window is not the one in `history.txt` but the one in the default file, `.bash_history`. I thought since after the `history -r` command I am executing `bash`, and that sources the `.bashrc` file, maybe `.bashrc` is doing something that affects the history I loaded.

Based on that, I tried the `rcfile` option in the answer linked above, so that I can include commands after `.bashrc`, resulting in the following `rcfile`:

```
FILE=~/.bashrc && test -f $FILE && source $FILE
history -c && history -r ~/history.txt
```

However, when I run the following command:

```
gnome-terminal -e "bash --rcfile rcfile"
```

The history in the new terminal is still the one from `.bash_history`. If I add the `history` command to the `rcfile` it shows that the history from `history.txt` was loaded, so **something after the `rcfile` is overwriting the history I load**.

I also found that if I **unset the `HISTFILE` variable** with `export HISTFILE=''` at the end of the `rcfile`, **the history from `history.txt` is not overwritten** and works. However, I do not want to unset `HISTFILE` because I do want the history to be saved to `.bash_history` when I use the newly opened terminal.

Finally, I found the `-o` option in bash, so I tried doing what I want with that. I changed my `rcfile` to:

```
FILE=~/.bashrc && test -f $FILE && source $FILE
history -c && history -r ~/saved/history.txt
set -o history
```

and ran the following command:

```
bash --rcfile rcfile.txt +o history
```

I was hoping that running `bash` with `+o history` would prevent the history from `history.txt` from being overwritten, while the `set -o history` command in the `rcfile` would reactivate the bash history. However, this also does not work as intended, as the history is the one from `history.txt` but then there is no more history logging and I have to manually enter `set -o history` for it to work.

So basically, everything I tried brings me back to the same question: **how do I open the new terminal with bash and *then* execute a command**, as if a user were entering it?

Additionally, I would like a better understanding of **what is happening after the `rcfile` is executed**, as I wasn't able to find any other relevant file that was being sourced. And **is there a way of disabling that behavior from the command line**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a workaround using the `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable and the `rcfile.txt` file mentioned in the question. You can run the command

```
gnome-terminal -e "bash --rcfile rcfile.txt"
```

Where the contents of `rcfile.txt` are the following:

```
FILE=~/.bashrc && test -f $FILE && source $FILE

my_init_func() {
    # Insert desired commands here. In my case, history -r history.txt
    PROMPT_COMMAND=`echo $1`
    eval $PROMPT_COMMAND
    unset -f $FUNCNAME
}

PROMPT_COMMAND="my_init_func \'$PROMPT_COMMAND\'"
```

What this does is source the default `.bashrc` if it exists in order to keep any other terminal configurations. Then, it defines a function that will run once when calling the `PROMPT_COMMAND` used in bash, then will unset itself and restore the original `PROMPT_COMMAND`.